# Why do I only get 300-400 Mbit/s on my 1000 Mbit/s network?

Tags: networking, performance, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

My setup is like this:

Laptop <--> Router <--> Desktop

They all support gigabit Ethernet. I'm using the 'iperf' TCP/IP benchmark on the laptop and desktop, and I've never gotten more than 400 Mbit/s raw throughput. The laptop is an Intel Core 2 Duo 2 GHz running Windows XP, the desktop is an Intel Core 2 quad 2.4 GHz running Windows 7. What things can I look at to maximize the network speed between them? Software settings? A way to know if my cable is not up to specifications? How to know if the gigabit Ethernet controller in one of the devices just isn't capable of hitting the max speed?

Answer (score 12):

1 Gbit/s is the theorectical maximum of this connection.

Many things can affect this.

Expect a hit in performance from your on-board NICs, as they will most likely be (based on device descriptions "Laptop" and "Desktop") host-based adapters that rely on the CPU to process the network traffic.  Therefore speed will be affected by the CPU doing other things (like getting the data from the HDDs to the networking sub-system for example).

Also, depending on what the "router" is, it may be trying to process the data as it passes from LAN port to LAN port, so its processing speeds may also be affecting the data transfer speeds, regardless of how fast its 'ports' are.

If I were you my next test would be to get myself a 'just long enough' CAT6 crossover patch cable and wire the notebook directly to the PC (you may be able to get away with a straight-through cable, as many NIC's support auto-crossover these days).

That way you (at least) can pretty easily eliminate or identify the router (and/or existing wiring) as a bottleneck.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable#Crossover_cable_pinouts for two possible pinouts for making a gigabit crossover cable.

Comment: Good info for sure. In this case if the user's not used to making a cable, and the goal is to eliminate possible slow-downs then he's probably better off using a factory-made cable.  Nothing much worse then a loose crimp. ;)

Comment: Just FYI, with gigabit ethernet, crossover cables are no longer needed. All gigabit ethernet controllers are required to be able to 'autosense' the cable, so you can use a standard cable to connect to gigabit ethernet devices together. I'll try connecting my laptop straight to the desktop and see if there's a difference.

Comment: @davr could you have any success?

Answer (score 9):

iperf uses a pretty small window size by default.

Increase the window or run it in UDP mode and it will easily saturate a 1 Gbit/s connection.

Comment: Didn't think of that, I'll try that.

Comment: You won't saturate it with consumer grade hardware.  The CPU generally gets limited by the PCI or PCI-Express bus.  i.e. CPU can't move data from RAM to network card quick enough.  Server grade hardware seems to do better.  I know, I'm a programmer and I've been trying to do just this.  Getting close but now limited by my own hardware.

Comment: worked for me, was banging my head for an hour trying to figure out why Windows iperf gives me 250mbit/sec and Ubuntu booted on the same machine gives me 925mbit/sec.
turns out iperf on windows defaults to 8k tcp window size and to 88k window size on linux.

Comment: @Omry, iperf on windows is a dog from several perspectives.  I have mostly given up and only run iperf under linux

Answer (score 4):

Jeff Atwood has some [good analysis](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000339.html) of why real-world throughput of a Gigabit network is closer to, in his calculations, 30MB/s.  (big 'B', not little 'b')

> ...you definitely shouldn't expect the perfect scaling we achieved moving from 10baseT to 100baseT. Without any major tweaking, you'll get only a fraction of the tenfold bandwidth improvement you might expect

Comment: That "pcattcp" tool he is using is a piece of crap.  My 900mhz linux netbook(which is probably as fast as his machine was in 2005) does 300MB/s over loopback.

Comment: Yeah, iperf gives noticably better performance over loopback than pcattcp does. I'll stick to iperf for testing for now unless I hear of somethign else that's better.

Comment: Also I already get higher than his 240mbit, and that article is 5 years old, so it's not as relevant anymore I think, seeing as how technology should have advanced greatly since then.

Comment: Well, considering that the loopback interface is virtual (nothing even gets transfered to the network card) you'd expect much better performance (basically it's then process to process and no HDD touched).  I'm getting 8.09 Gbits/s (1035Mbytes/s) over the loopback interface.

Answer (score 3):

If everything is gigabit, you could try to [enable jumbo frames](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/content/view/30201/54/).  One of my friends did this with his home computer and noticed a huge increase in throughput.  However, there are some drawbacks for low-latency applications like VOIP, as mentioned in the article.

Comment: The increase should not that dramatic for most applications.  All this will do is mean less TCP or UDP protocol overhead per packet.  Also, for best results your switch/routers should also support jumbo frames.  I doubt his would.

Comment: For *any* results your switches have to support jumbo frames.  There's no way for L2-only device to send back a 'Packet too big' ICMP error to tell your machine it needs to use a smaller packet size.

Answer (score 1):

Did you say you're using a router?  is that an off the shelf consumer grade router (not switch)?

I'd say thats most likely your bottleneck.  To verify this,
Plug the laptop directly into the desktop.
Set your Laptop and desktop to use a static IP address like 192.168.1.10 (laptop), 192.168.1.11 (desktop).

This should allow the laptop to talk directly to the desktop.  Run iperf between them and report the result back here.

That should work as most modern network cards can auto-sense transmit/receive wires unlike the old days when you used to have to build a crossover cable.

If you see a marked increase then your router is the culprit.  Some of them have switches on the back, others can actually route between ports.  Many of these routers are terrible performers.  If you do find this is the problem then if I were you I'd either upgrade the router (which is probably fine for internet use) or go and buy yourself a GigE switch and cascade that onto the router switch.  Plug your laptop and desktop into the switch.  That way, they will bypass the router to talk to each other.

Make sure you change your laptop & desktop back to DHCP when you've completed the experiment.

To give you an idea, you should get I would think 650Mbit/s and above.  iperf doesn't use the harddrive unless you tell it to.  So it's memory to memory or really testing the network.

On of the other bottlenecks is actually how quick your CPU can transfer data from the memory to the network card.  Networks that are on PCI express seem to operate better.  I think laptops are generally fairly cheaply built these days so if you don't see much above that then this could be the other bottleneck.

Also, consumer grade switches can often only cope switching 1GB between any two ports whereas high end managed switches can switch at wire speed on all ports simultaneously.
That's part of the reason they cost so much more.

Answer (score 1):

We've performed numerous test and it boiled down to the Operating System.

If we go from Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.04 (same with CentOS for Linux machines), the speed throughput is  ~938-941 MBits/s constant.  If we go from Windows 7 x64 SP1 Ultimate to Ubuntu 11.04, it varies from ~440-475 MBits/s.  If we move from Windows 2008 R2SP1 x64 to Ubuntu 11.04, the speed measures ~435-635 MBits/s.

As you can see, Linux based machines fully utilize the Gigabit links compared to Windows.  We are now investigating settings in Windows that would result in the same throughput as Linux on same hardware.  Hard drive limitations are not a factor since this is in memory.  For the record, the machines we used had 7200 RPM drives with SATA 3.0.  Both the Ubuntu 11.04 (or Linux base) and Windows exceeded the theoretical speed of those SATA links.

Comment: Thanks for the info, please update your answer if you find any settings which affect the speed on windows

Comment: this makes me wonder if iperf isn't the only part of Windows that defaults to a smaller packet size than Linux, see http://superuser.com/a/95587/16966

Answer (score 0):

Transfer speeds are only as good as the weakest link in the chain. It might not be the network speed but the write/read speed of your Hard Drives.

You can download [RamDisk](http://www.romexsoftware.com/) software and create a RamDisk on both computers. Place a decent size file inside of it and do a transfer over the network between the RamDisks. This should show you the actual speed of your network that won't be bottlenecked by your Hard Drive speeds.

Comment: That's why I mentioned 'iperf', but I guess it's not that common of a tool. Basically it tests network speed directly, without reading/writing to the Hard Drive, so that's not the bottleneck there. I do realize that HDD can be a bottleneck in real world usage though.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but recently we got the following result with `iperf` between two Linux boxes (8 core, 2.66 GHz each):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.74.15, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  192 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.74.25 port 54016 connected with 192.168.74.15 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.10 GBytes   941 Mbits/sec
```

with MTU=1500 (i.e. not using jumbo frames). That should give you an idea of what performance is in principle possible.

The network cards (lspci output) are:

```
82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

on both sides.

You might want to check the CPU load on the server and especially on the client side and see whether this is close to 100%. Even though I have to say that on our system the busiest core is 80% (83%) idle on the receiver (sender) side while the other 7 seem to be 100% idle (checked with `mpstat`).

This is running `iperf` without the `-u` option, i.e. this uses TCP.

Comment: I think you should be getting > 500 or 600 mbits/s on 1 - 2 year old desktop hardware.

Answer (score -4):

davr,
    Unlike fibre channel and similar technologies which use sophisticated bandwidth allocation schemes, ethernet is a 'listen and squawk' protocol. Ethernet first listens if anyone is currently transmiting, if so wait if not then send.  The problem is that if two or more parties wishing to transmit are listening at the same time, they'll send at the same time as well!  This will cause collisions and retransmits.  Fancy switches eliminate a lot of this, but not all.

With ethernet you should expect see about 30-40 percent bandwidth (Looks like your getting this . . . I could be wrong on the exact #, much depends on switch quality and etc) before lots of collisions start to occur, with fabric technology is something like 80%. Ethernet is cheap, fibre channel is not . . . I'm not sure what 4G ethernet does to get around this . . . it might a have a more 'fabric' like network topology similar to fibre channel and friends. This is an oversimplification, but is essentially correct.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using a 'dumb' hub. I think most people these days will use intelligent switches or routers which handle connecting devices directly to each other, eliminating collisions. Also my test involves only two devices connected to a single router, so collisions wouldn't be a problem in my particular case.

Comment: davr - excuse while I play devils' advocate for a moment . . . What prevents your two hosts from attempting to talk at the same time?  Also, you didn't mention what kind of data is being transmitted . . . is it almost exclusively TCP or are there lots of data streaming (audio, video, etc)?  Are both computers streaming data simultaneously or is there a more precisely demarcated client/server relationship?

Comment: I'm using a special TCP/IP benchmarking program where only one computer sends, and the other listens. But even so, Ethernet is full duplex...if you have only two machines, they can both send and receive full bandwidth to each other at the same time.